# Objective C Properties memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have to show the user details from `NSUserDefaults` in more than 5 view controllers. So i have created a `NSObject` subclass, which will load the user details from server when the first view controllers `viewDidLoad` is called.

Here is my First view controller viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    // Getting the Current User Details
    CurrentUserDetails *userDetails = [[CurrentUserDetails alloc]init];
    [userDetails initializeTheCurrentUserData];

//CurrentUserDetails is my NSObject class

}
```

And

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CurrentUserDetails : NSObject

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *memberName;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *designation;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *memberType;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *entreprenuer;

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSDate *expiryDate;

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSData *imageData;


- (void) initializeTheCurrentUserData;

@end
```

and implementation

```
@implementation CurrentUserDetails


- (void) initializeTheCurrentUserData{

    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userDictionary"];
    NSDictionary *retrievedDictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

    self.memberName = [retrievedDictionary valueForKey:@"Name"];

    self.designation = [retrievedDictionary valueForKey:@"Designation"];

    self.memberType = [[retrievedDictionary valueForKey:@"Member_type"] stringValue];

    self.expiryDate = [retrievedDictionary valueForKey:@"Expiry"];
    self.kanaraEntreprenuer = [retrievedDictionary valueForKey:@"CityName"];

    NSString *imageUrl = [retrievedDictionary valueForKey:@"Member_image"];

    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[GlobalVariables getBaseURLForMemberImage],imageUrl]]];


}
```

And when iam trying to take the details from other class like this..

```
CurrentUserDetails *userDetails = [[CurrentUserDetails alloc]init];
    memberName = userDetails.memberName;

    designation = userDetails.designation;    

    memberType = userDetails.memberType;

    dateFromServer = userDetails.expiryDate;
    entreprenuer = userDetails.entreprenuer;
    imageDataFromServer = userDetails.imageData;
```

I am getting nil values.

But if call initializeTheCurrentUserData method each time, i am getting the exact values. I though once a property is assigned with a value , we can use the property for entire program. I'm getting confusion.. Can anyone please tell me about this????. Do i need to call initializeTheCurrentUserData everytime when i want to use the values?

Comment: No Need to initialize again server response you can store using setter and getter method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set a property of an instance, that property remains for that instance. You, however, are creating new instances with `[[CurrentUserDetails alloc] init]`. Each new instance will be initialized with default values (`nil` for `NSString`).

Call `-initializeTheCurrentUserData` in `-init` so each instance will be initialized with the values from user defaults.

```
@implementation CurrentUserDetails

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        [self initializeTheCurrentUserData];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initializeTheCurrentUserData {
    …
}
```